# "this field is required" error in file upload form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to do a form with file uploading. I got "this field is required" even though I choose a file in the form. Below is my code. 
It works once before, I don't why it doesn't work suddenly.Thanks in advance.

Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from time import time
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.', '_'), filename)

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user =  models.OneToOneField(User)
  contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  tag_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  layout = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Form

```
from django import forms
from models import UserProfile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('contact_number','tag_id', 'layout')
```

View

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
        return HttpResponse("Update success")
    else:
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
        return HttpResponse("Update error")

else:
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
args['form'] = form
args['full_name'] = request.user.username
return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

profile.html

```
<div align = "center">
<h2 >Profile</h2>
<form id="profile_form" method="POST" action="/accounts/profile/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>{{full_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tag ID</td>
            <td>{{form.tag_id}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact number</td>
            <td>{{form.contact_number}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Layout</td>
            <td>{{form.layout}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
<input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" />
    </form>
    <DIV id="saved"></DIV>
    </div>
```